# hibhernate and Mysql connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HEY");
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("pallavi");
        user.setGoal(100);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

User.java

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int total;
    private int goal;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public int getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }
    public void setGoal(int goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }

}
```

HibernateUtilities.java

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static{

        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        }
        catch(HibernateException exception){
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
             exception.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    /*
    public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateUtilities.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    } */


}
```

Hibernate config file :-----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
  <mapping resource="com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User mapping file-----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 1 May, 2017 12:09:45 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.simpleprogrammer.User" table="USERS">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="total" type="int">
            <column name="TOTAL" />
        </property>
        <property name="goal" type="int">
            <column name="GOAL" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Everything is working fine but data is not getting stored in database, i dont understand what is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You create the `User` entity, but you do not tell the persistence provider to actually manage it and eventually physically store it in the database:

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("pallavi");
    user.setGoal(100);

    session.persist(user);
```

Alternatively you can use `save` method.

This is the case when creating a new entity. If you were to update an existing entity, which you queries within the same transaction, then you would not need to explicitly call the `update` or `merge` operation as the persistence provider would do that for you implicitly on transaction commit.